# Magento2 Getting an Error: Call to a member function initValidationStrategy()

Tags: magento2

[image]

**Error:** Call to a member function initValidationStrategy() on null in  vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import.php:664
Stack trace:

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur when you try to export products from Magento without loading the product model first You can try commenting out the line that calls the getMetaTitle() function in the _prepareLayout() method of the Import.php file Alternatively, you can override the class and add a condition to check if the product model is loaded before calling the function.

Comment: I added a new entity option "New Price Product Update" When I try to update the already existing product price getting this error,

Error: Call to a member function initValidationStrategy() on null in  /vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import.php:664
Stack trace:
 vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Import/Validate.php(53):

Comment: Check for null before passing the value, otherwise it will cause an error.

Comment: https://www.useblackbox.io/editor?id=8e9fe04a-d551-4f53-9d5f-9fedbcb44247


https://www.useblackbox.io/editor?id=8bf5b1ce-8f5e-4405-8fc0-3e891570cda0
can you help to fix that issue i attached my file,

Comment: I'm new to Magento2 help me fix the error.